# Search across multiple pdfs with indexing

Tags: windows, shell, unix, search, pdf

I have 20,000 pdf files in a directory tree. I need to search through them, fast. It could be a GUI program running under Windows, or a command line interface running under Windows or Cygwin (or even a Java or Ruby library). The catch is, it needs to implement indexing. (Or I need a quick shell script to  implement indexing and another one to search through the index).

Adobe Reader would work great, only is there any way to allow for indexing?

EDIT: I found *an* answer that works for my 64 bit Windows 7: http://www.documentsnap.com/how-to-fix-pdf-search-in-windows-7-64-bit/

Still, my question about shell script still stands.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you search for a certain text across pdf files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012711/how-do-you-search-for-a-certain-text-across-pdf-files)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best approach to implement search for searching documents (PDF, XML, HTML, MS Word)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/831738/249690)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to search pdf-files' contents in terminal](http://stackoverflow.com/q/694049/249690)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Project Thoughts: Searching Directory of PDFs](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3416004/249690)

Comment: @Bobrovsky, with the possible exception of Lucene, I don't think the solutions at the other questions allow for indexing. Lucene seems a steep learning curve, but definitely a good lead.